# Transform a non-linear differential equation into a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, economics, nonlinear-analysis

Following the work of *Yaoji Lu - 1967* (here's [a link](https://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.es/&httpsredir=1&article=4405&context=rtd) to the full paper) I got stuck at the step when the author transform a non-linear differential equation into a linear equation (***eq. 3.9 pag. 19***).

More precisely he starts from this equation:

$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{Y}{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1}\cdot Y^{\frac{1}{b}}$$

Then define $Z=Y^{1-\frac{1}{b}}$ and eventually get:

$$\frac{dZ}{dX}+\frac{1-b}{b}\cdot \frac{1}{X}\cdot Z=\alpha \frac{1-b}{b}\cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1}$$

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: It's Bernouilli 's equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Bernouilli's equation 
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{Y}{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1}\cdot Y^{\frac{1}{b}}$$
Divide by $y^{1/b}$
$$Y^{-\frac{1}{b}}Y'=\frac{Y^{1-\frac 1b}}{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1} $$
$$(1-\frac 1b )Y^{-\frac{1}{b}}Y'=(1-\frac 1b)(\frac{Y^{1-\frac 1b}}{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1} )$$
$$(Y^{1-\frac{1}{b}})'=(1-\frac 1b)(\frac{Y^{1-\frac 1b}}{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1} )$$
Substitute $Z=Y^{1-\frac 1b}$
$$Z'=(1-\frac 1b)(\frac Z{X}-\alpha \cdot X^{-\frac{c}{b}-1} )$$

Comment: Thank you so much! ;)

Comment: toy're welcome @Alessandro

Comment: @Alessandro Why do you not click on the accept answer button to the left of the answer?

Comment: Done, thanks. I am still learning :P